# Display glitches on a MBPro 15 inch Late 2013 (base model) (video)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, video

I have a late 2013 Macbook Pro Retina 15 inch with integrated graphics (base model), which has display glitches that occur sporadically. This seems to happen more often when an external display is connected.

https://streamable.com/ip8n8q

In the video, you can see the display glitches appear. Sometimes the glitches disappear when I move my cursor over it. This wasn't the case now, moving the cursor over to the external monitor fixed the issue.

My question: What could cause this and is there any known fix for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have one of the Macbook Pros with an acknowledged video issue - unfortunately the free repair program ended long ago. Apple used to have a page where you could check if your model was affected, but it is long gone.
There's some info on https://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/macbook-problems-recalls-3699153/

A 2013 model is probably not worth paying to repair these days. The product is listed as Vintage, so Apple would probably repair it, but at cost.
There's a list of Vintage & Obsolete Macs here - [Obtaining service for your Apple product after an expired warranty](https://support.apple.com/HT201624)

You could try running hardware diagnostics - Hold D at boot - & see what is reported.